# Jest/Typescript throwing error for missing property that’s not missing

Tags: javascript, object, jestjs, ts-jest

I have this object literal:

```js
export const Typography: ITypographyBase = {
  fontFamily: '"IBM Plex Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif',
  fontSize: BASE_FONT_SIZE,
  name: 'Typography',
  toJS: function () {
    return Object.entries(this).reduce(
      (acc, [key, value]) => {
        if (!isValidCSSProperty(kebabCase(key))) return acc;
        const transformedValue = this.transformValue(key, value, this.fontSize);
        return { ...acc, [key]: transformedValue };
      }, {},
    );
  },
  transformValue: function (property, input, fontSize) {
    switch (property) {
      case 'fontSize':
        return toNumberWithUnit(input / BASE_FONT_SIZE, 'rem');
      case 'letterSpacing':
        return toNumberWithUnit(input / fontSize, 'em');
      case 'lineHeight':
        return toNumberWithUnit(input / fontSize, 'em');
      default: return input;
    }
  },
};
```

And this simple test using Jest with `ts-jest`:

```js
describe('computed values', () => {
  test('fontSize', () => {
    const styles = {
      ...Typography,
      fontSize: 24,
    };
    const type = styles.toJS();
    console.log('type', Object.keys(type));
    expect(type.fontSize).toEqual('1.5rem');
  });
});
```

When run, the test throws the following error:

```
src/lib/tokens/typography.test.ts:17:17 - error TS2339: Property 'fontSize' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

… but the `console.log('type', Object.keys(type));` line echoes the following response:

```
type ['fontFamily', 'fontSize']
```

What gives?

Comment: Are you sure it's the *test* that throws? The error you're quoting seems like a *TypeScript* error which should appear at compile time, not on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that the test will pass if I do either of the following:

1. Add type assertion to the result of `styles.toJS()`:

```js
const type = styles.toJS() as ITypographyBase;
```

2. Add `// @ts-nocheck` to the top of the file.

Comment: You can also do `const styles :  ITypographyBase = {`.